# A triangle in CSS that takes the whole width with a fixed height?

Tags: html, css, shapes

I'm trying to make a triangle in CSS that takes the whole width of the parent with a fixed height.

I successfully did so with a linear-gradient like this:

```css
.triangle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, blue 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

But the diagonal doesn't look crisp. How could I do the same in CSS without using gradient?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can blur the edge a bit

```css
.triangle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, blue 49.5%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

*the border approach as mention could be done this way to be similar :*

```css
.triangle {
  width:0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 120px 100vw;
  border-color:transparent transparent transparent blue ;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Best is to use an SVG ....

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to make a triangle out of the border. Since CSS does not allow using percentage in `border-width`, I'm using `100vh` instead of `100%`.

Please try this:

```
.triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 120px 100vw;
    border-color:transparent transparent transparent blue ;
}
```

Comment: Interesting! But your triangle is 100% the height, not the width.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try without gradient property using border-width.I have      implemented one using border-width which gives the boundaries more crisp. Here is the runable version.

```css
.triangle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, blue 50%, transparent 50%);
}
.container{
  width : 300px;
}
.triangleUsingbordermethod {
    
    border-top-color: blue;
    border-top: 60px solid blue;
    border-left: 50% solid black;
    border-left: 150px solid blue;
    border-right: 150px transparent solid;
    border-bottom: 60px transparent solid;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
 <div class="triangleUsingbordermethod"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why do not you make a working snippet in your answer instead using a trick to link it ?

Comment: Hey @GCyrillus:I was not knowing how to do it.I learn it now.Thanks